# polar chart data flipping

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I am trying to flip the data to 45 degree instead of 135 degree as per below figures.

my code for ploar plotting is

```
R= ( file_array.max(axis=1)/np.amax(file_array.max(axis=1)))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(radians,abs(R))
ax.set_xlabel('relative amplitude')
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(1, 0.2)
ax.set_thetamin(0)
ax.set_thetamax(180)
ax.set_thetagrids(range(0, 181, 30))
```

Need Image Like this
[image]

As per my code

[image]

Comment: You mean `ax.plot([np.pi - i for i in radians], abs(R))`? Shouldn't that be addressed when creating `radians`?

Comment: yes it changes to what I expected. Thank you very much